# How to add/edit related entity while staying on form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As I'am a newcomer to Web programming I'am stuck with quite a common use case. To keep it simple I'll use Invoice example. While entering Invoice I can select existing customer from DropDownList. But if customer don't exist I have to create it, and then select it. Surely I can navigate to Customers, add a new customer then go back to Invoice and start from begining but this is surely not a way to go. I'am sure there is some sort of 'best practice' way to deal with it as instead Invoice there could be a long input form with many realated records and losing populated fields could not be an option.

In WPF I would use modal views. Supposedly the same approach could be used here but I haven't found similar example maybe using wrong terms.

I'am aware that jQuery/javascript is a way to go but still dont't now what would be 'best practice' look alike. Also, is there some good UI aproach for alike inputs to go without javascript?

Can someone turn me toward right direction and release me from too many guesses?

Answer (score 0):

i think best way is use jquery

create dialog-form and show on new customer btn click and save it using ajax and on success load data to your dropdown list using another ajax calling

1) dialog

```
<div class="modal fade" id="dialog-AddPublishers" style="display: none !important;">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add Publisher</h4>
        </div>
        <form role="form" id="frmAddPublishers">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group LeftPadding10px">
                    <label for="Product">Publishers Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="PublishersName" id="PublishersName" class="form-control InputBoxWidth autosuggest" placeholder="Enter Publishers Name">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="SavePublishers()" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAdd">Save Publishers</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

2)click event

```
function ShowAddPublishers() {
        $("#dialog-AddPublishers").modal('show');
        $('#PublishersName').val('');
    };
```

3) ajax calls

```
 function SavePublishers() {

        var pathName = window.location.pathname;
        var virtualdir = pathName.split('/');
        var directory = "/" + virtualdir[1] + "/ManageLibrary/ManagePublisher/AddPublisherJsonData";


        $.ajax({
            url: directory,
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify
                ({
                    PublishersName: $('#PublishersName').val(),
                }),

            success: function (data) {

                //$("#dialog-AddPublishers").show().delay(3000).queue(function (n) {
                //    $(this).hide(); n();
                //    $('#PublishersID').focus();
                //});
                $("#dialog-AddPublishers").modal('hide');

                BindPublishers();
            },
            error: function (data) {

                $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
            }
        });
    }
```

4) rebind dropdown list

```
function BindPublishers() {

        var pathName = window.location.pathname;
        var virtualdir = pathName.split('/');
        var directory = "/" + virtualdir[1] + "/ManageLibrary/ManagePublisher/GetPublisherJsonList";

        $.getJSON(directory, null, function (data) {
            $('#PublishersID').empty();
            $('#PublishersID').append($('<option></option>').text('None').attr('value', ''));
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#PublishersID').append($('<option></option>').text(data[i].PublishersName).attr('value', data[i].PublishersID));
            }
        }).done(function () {

            $('#PublishersID').focus();
        });
    }
```

Comment: tnx. Looks exactly what I looked for. I'll try it later. Beside this, only to satisfy curiosity, what would be a possible way for this kind of edits without javascript? No need for example, simple comment or description will sufice

Comment: There is no way to stay on the same page and make calls to server methods without using ajax/javascript. Note also the second call to call the server and repopulate the dropdown is not really necessary. You could just append the new `<option>` to the dropdown in the `SavePublishers` method